# Backbone.js collectin throw the error

Tags: backbone.js

I am(as a beginner) making a small backbone function to append my links, for this i using the collection to be assigned model,

But the collection throw the error.. any one can correct my code please?

```
$(function(){
    var Model = new Backbone.Model({
        data:[
                {name:'Yahoo',href:'http://www.yahoo.com'},
                {name:'Gmail',href:'http://www.gmail.com'},
                {name:'Bing',href:'http://www.bing.com'}
              ]    
    });

    var Collection = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:Model // is this not correct way to do?
    });

    var View = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:'#container',
        events:{
            'click button':'render'
            },
        initialize:function(){
            this.collection = new Collection(); //throw the error!
            this.template = $('#temp').children();
        },
        render:function(){
            var data = this.collection.get('data');
            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                var li = this.template.clone().find('a')
                .attr('href',data[i].href)
                .text(data[i].name).end();
                this.$el.find('ul').append(li);
            }
        }
    });

    var myLink = new View();

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models are used to store and manage individual chunks of data. In your case that would be a single name/href pair. Usually you use `Backbone.Model.extend` to create a model "class" with all your model-specific methods and properties and then you create instances of that model with `new` or set that model "class" as a collection's [`model` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) so that the collection can create new instances of the model.

Your model should look more like this:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        href: ''
    }
});
```

Notice that there's no `new` in there as we're just making a "class" to base our model instances on. Then we hook the model up to a collection (again using `extend` with no `new`):

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Model
});
```

Now you can [create an instance of the collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor) and hand it an array of data for the models:

```
var links = new Collection([
    { name: 'Yahoo', href: 'http://www.yahoo.com' },
    { name: 'Gmail', href: 'http://www.gmail.com' },
    { name: 'Bing',  href: 'http://www.bing.com'  }
]);
```

You'll often pass the collection to the view rather than making the view instantiate the collection; [Backbone will automatically](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) set `this.collection` if you say `new SomeView({ collection: some_collection })` so you can:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = $('#temp').children();
    },
```

and say `new View({ collection: links })` and access the collection through `this.collection` elsewhere in the view.

A collection is a collection of several models (sort of like an array) and it will have [various useful Underscore methods mixed in](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so you can iterate through the collection like this:

```
render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(link) {
        var li = this.template.clone().find('a').attr('href', link.get('href')).text(link.get('name'));
        this.$('ul').append(li);
    }, this);
}
```

Also notice the use of [`get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) to access model attributes, model attributes and object properties are different things. You can also use [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) to flatten all the data at once. The final `this` argument to [`each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) makes `this` inside the callback the view. Backbone already supplies a `this.$el.find()` alias in the view's [`this.$()`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) method so I switch to that as well.

Here's a simplified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/WSqLM/

Comment: Very thanks to you. This is not just simply a answer, as well a good explanation to upgrade my self. thanks again!